# Need to calculate derived metrics in a classifier

Tags: feature-selection, classifier

I have a classifier that predicts a class given roughly 100 datapoints. The classifier that tends to perform best on my data is **RandomForest**.

I have a lot of metrics such as revenue for each of the past months, number of web traffic coming from different sources etc.

Here is my question, if I should calculate derived metrics as input for the model (e.g. year over year growth %, % traffic from each source etc.) or just put the features into the model as it is?

Comment: You can add derived features.